# Deploying a .Net App Source Control (SVN) over 32-bit AND 64-bit dev stations

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, svn, tortoisesvn

**Here is the situation :** 
Our Dev Team has heterogeneous OS systems, scattered between 32-bit and 64-bit. This is not ideal, we are actually planning to homogenize our infrastructure, but in the meantime we have to deal with it.

The issue is that when a 32-bit developer checks out a 64-bit solution on SVN, he has to manually change the target platforms all over again to get it compiled (not to mention other side problems)

**My question is :** 
What clean (though temporary) solution could be addressed in such situation, permitting each developer to keep his default project/platform settings while checking out and in from SVN.

I guess that -at least for the first time a project/solution is checked out, a dev still has to tweak the setting manually to compile it properly. After that, according to relevant SVN filters, it is possible to ignore some settings files (which ones, by the way?)

I am open to all clever and detailed suggestions.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you checking in .suo and .user files into source control?  As these should be developer specific and **should not** be included.   Pretty sure the suo maintains the build state of the project for each user.

Another option, is execute builds from scripts.  For example I have 4 different build script files wired up with autohotkey to build in the background release and debug mode version of a project.   This can be configured via msbuild or nant on how you want the project's configuration to look.

This has a benefit of not tying up visual studio.

It has a downside of further work customizing your solution, but long term I think you're in a better situation.

Comment: Yes this makes sense, I know that, but... Are you sure that target info (x64/x32) are included in .suo files ?

Comment: You second proposition about scripting out builds might be of fair interest, indeed. if you could a short example and how to tie it to a hotkey that would help. Otherwise i'll just find out by myself. Thanx

Comment: @Mika, I use Autohotkey for shortcut launching to the batch files.  See http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm  Basically you wire up a hotkey to the bat/cmd file.   ANd yes I just tested 2 copies of a .SUO file renaming then each after changing build options, the data is stored in the .SUO dealing with user preferred build settings. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171481.aspx on how to perform different msbuild configurations

Comment: Thanks, i'll dig this track. I thought that the hotkey was a custom VS hotkey bindable to an external build script. I know autohotkey very well I used it to simulate early-morning logins to a time tracking application to fool my previous company's system when I wanted to come late to work :-P

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason you're specifically targeting solutions at 32bit and 64bit? 
eg: Native, unmanaged DLLs?

If you use the "Any CPU" platform option, then .NET will natively run it in either 64bit or 32bit mode depending on what's available on the machine.

Edit: 
The other option if you *must* set the CPU Mode statically is to set up an x86-32 and x86-64 build configuration, and then have your developers select the appropriate build configuration on their end.

I would strongly suggest figuring out what's wrong with your AnyCPU mode though, as if you don't - you need two install packages for your users based on their OS mode.

Comment: This is a relevant point : For some reason, the "Any CPU" option's default behavior is sometimes inconsistent, switching to 32x on 64x Platforms, so I preferred to force it to 64x on 64x platforms to avoid the mess. Maybe there was something we were doing wrong, but we did not figure out what.

Comment: @Mika Jacobi - Updated my answer. You can set up multiple build configurations which may help here.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you are using only managed dotnet-code (no native 32/64bit code) every body can work with **32Bit solution only** on 64bit and on 32bit dev-stations. On win7-64 visual studio also is a 32 bit app.

Comment: Negative : Actually all the point from that is that x64 stations are more powerful and we need the code on them to be x64 for more computing efficiency.